# Headerdoc with delegate Protocols - Swift and xcode 7.2

Tags: xcode, swift, appledoc, headerdoc

I have defined a protocol and added HeaderDoc documentation to the method in this protocol. It appears correctly when I Option+Click the method:

[image: Image of documentation in the protocol]

However, when I Option+Click the implementation within a controller that implements this protocol, the documentation is not showing up:

[image]

My expectation is that the documentation I wrote for the protocol would show up in the controller, similar to the documentation from Apple:

[image]

How do I get my protocol documentation to be visible elsewhere?

Comment: Looks like you documented one method, but then tried to bring up docs for a different method.

Comment: I uploaded the wrong image. Thank you Petah :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you document the protocol's method implementation within a protocol extension, the documentation will then be visible within any type that conforms to the protocol.

*If you omit the extension's documentation, the `canDo` documentation from the protocol doesn't show up anywhere else but the protocol itself, as you noticed.*

```
protocol Doable {
    /// Does something
    func canDo()
}

extension Doable {
    /// Does something really well
    func canDo() {
        print("Did it!")
    }
}

struct Task: Doable {
    init() {
        canDo()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you petah! That's sad that we need to implement an extension to be able to see the protocol documentation. Maybe in the future it will work without it. :)

Comment: @VictorTavares You can always [file a bug report and/or a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com/)!